# Umbraco7: Set up multiple /media/ blob containers within the same Azure Storage account

Tags: azure, azure-storage, umbraco, azure-blob-storage, umbraco7

We have multiple Umbraco sites that we need to migrate from an on-premise to Azure web apps.

Each site has its own /media/ folder and as all the images require a big storage space (~2gb) and many read/write operations, we thought of using an Azure Storage Account via Blob containers solution for this.

Is it correct to say that using a single Azure Storage Account to serve all the sites' /media folders via Blob containers will cut costs rather than using separate storage accounts for every site?

We've found the [UmbracoFileSystemProviders.Azure](https://our.umbraco.com/packages/collaboration/umbracofilesystemprovidersazure/) package which is great, but can't find any details on how to achieve what's stated in the title of this post.

**Question**: How can we set up multiple /media/ blob containers within the same Azure Storage account to serve the images of multiple Umbraco sites?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can indeed use the one Azure Storage Account; just set up different blob containers for each website - they actually don't need to be called "media".  for example, I've set the containerName to `Site1Media` in the following example:

```
  <Provider alias="media" type="Our.Umbraco.FileSystemProviders.Azure.AzureBlobFileSystem, Our.Umbraco.FileSystemProviders.Azure">
<Parameters>
    <add key="containerName" value="Site1Media"/>
    <add key="rootUrl" value="https://youritteam.blob.core.windows.net/"/>
    <add key="connectionString" value="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=[Account];AccountKey=[Key]"/>
    <!--
    Optional configuration value determining the maximum number of days to cache items in the browser.
    Defaults to 365 days.
  -->
    <add key="maxDays" value="365"/>
    <!--
    When true this allows the VirtualPathProvider to use the deafult "media" route prefix regardless 
    of the container name.
  -->
    <add key="useDefaultRoute" value="true"/>
    <!--
    When true blob containers will be private instead of public what means that you can't access the original blob file directly from its blob url.
  -->
    <add key="usePrivateContainer" value="false"/>
</Parameters>
```

The other thing about Azure Storage is that you only pay for the data you use; so it's not going to cost you extra to set up multiple Storage Accounts - there's probably very little benefit in having one Storage Account for multiple websites; and you may find it much easier later on to have one Storage Account per website - particularly if you want to move the website to another subscription down the track.